# Does the light novel tell of the passing of time during Itami's missions?

Tags: gate

In the *GATE* anime (ep. 3-4), Itami goes to Coda village, then returns to Arnus Hill with the children and the left-behind refugees.

From the time he left to when he returns, the JSDF camp went from a tent park to a fortified pentagonal structure with buildings.

Now XXI century building tech can make [a 57-floor-tall building in 19 days](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2989769/Building-skyscraper-Lego-style-Chinese-firm-builds-57-storey-block-record-19-days-rate-three-floors-day.html), but we are talking about reinforced military-grade structures with materials being shipped through a portal, so YMMV.

The anime never tells how many days Itami was away during his Coda Village reconaissance sortie.

Does the light novel tell of the passing of time during Itami's mission?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is never told. However, it is possible to make a fair estimate, while keeping in mind that it was never like that in the manga.

In the anime and manga alike, Itami travels to the Elven forest from Coda village, so roughly 7-13 days, if they were able to make peaceful contact and even were able to learn basic rules of the language. The 7-13 here refers ro the time spent at Coda.

Travelling to the Elven forest would take roughly 1-2 days. The time they spent searching for survivors in Tuka's village adds 1.

When they return to Coda, presumably in a similar timeframe as when they travelled to Coda, the entire village began to evacuate, so roughly 1 day passed at the start.

It is mentioned that rain and several other problems were exhausting the villagers, so presuming that, we can add 2-3 days there. The fire dragon also arrived, so that would add half a day.

So while it is never revealed, I believe that roughly 13 - 21 days were spent in the Coda area. However, I seriously disregard against using the anime' timeline because there are multiple mistakes made while speeding up the sequence of events. But if you like, this is my estimate.